# access key value of object

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to make this page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV1Ij.png)

So far i am able to make the above red banner and the google maps. 
Following is the api being used to fetch data:
http://test.poletalks.com/websites/getData

I have created 3 components for representing the 3 rectangles.
I am having parse error in the 1st rectangle.
This file uses data which is

```
{"store":{"id":"58da327fa0358e186624b72daaa","name":"NIT, Calicut","store_type":"Education","description":"National Institute of Technology, Calicut is a leading institute of engineering and architecture in India. The motto of the institute is 'From Darkness, Lead us unto Light'","location":[75.9342274000001,11.3216676],"formatted_address":"National Institute Of Technology, Kattangal, Kerala, India","image":"http://res.cloudinary.com/poletalks/image/upload/v1472055369/Nitc_my3vig.jpg"}
```

I am trying to represent the first rectangle as a table. However i am not able to access the object using ngFor.

details.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <table class="table" border="1">
      <tr *ngFor="let #item of stored">
      <td *ngFor="#key of c | keys">{{key}}:{{c[key]}}  </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have created a pipe to convert the object to array.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'keypipe'
})
export class KeypipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args: string[]): any {
    let keys = [];
        for (let key in value) {
          keys.push(key);
        }
        return keys;
      }
    }
  //  return null;
```

However I am getting parse error.. please help me implement this page.

Comment: why not just use `myKeys=Object.keys(myObject)`?

Comment: where should i use this??????in .ts file?

Comment: This is just javascript, so yea...put it in your .ts file. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: What exactly is the problem, displaying these rectangles? (where is these rectangles coming from, can't see in your code). Or is the problem showing the complete table?

Comment: please refer the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV1Ij.png

Comment: Okay, but what is the problem? I see the table with data and rectangles, so what is not working?

Comment: I am not able to print the 1st table.....where the heading is NIT Calicut

Comment: What is `c`? Your question is pretty unclear to me, I ***Guess*** `stored` is your complete JSON ??? but what is `c`? You really should explain more :)

Comment: yes stored is complete json......forget c it is nothing

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the pipe in this case, you have two objects inside an Object, so you can just use the property paths. First for showing the content of `store`, something in the line of the following:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>{{stored?.store?.name}}</legend>
  <p>{{stored?.store?.description}}</p>
  <!-- rest of the properties -->
  <img src="{{stored?.store?.image}}" />
</fieldset>
```

Notice we are using the [**safe navigation operator**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) to safeguard `null`/`undefined` values.

Then over to your table view, there we want to access the content of `store_admins`, so your table should look something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let admin of stored?.store_admins">
    <td>{{admin.login_id}}</td>
    <!-- rest of the properties -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

That should do it! :)

Here's a

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WRpBhOHGxR77oQaXGpgO?p=preview)

Comment: Well, I have copied the exact JSON from the page you provided, so you need to check if you are actually receiving data at all, since nothing is shown. Can you check the network tab that you are actually receiving data, because as you can see, it works well in the plunker :)

Comment: how do i shift the nit calicut fieldset to be on left of the maps? and how do i insert the image like the way in the question

Comment: I added how image can be inserted to code (check updated answer), as for the design of the template, that is ***way*** beyond the scope of this question. That's a really big task with CSS, and it cannot be incorporated in this question or answer. You need to try something first yourself, learn about CSS and if you encounter problems, then ask a new question about CSS particularly, that is a whole other question than this ;)